# Using Notepad++ with MiKTeX on Windows

Tags: miktex, windows, editors

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows. So far I've been using LeD to compile my PDFs (using `pdflatex`). I want to start using Notepad++ to compile my LaTeX PDFs as I've lately become very fond of this editor.

Would anyone be able to point me to a way to configure Notepad++ with shortcuts to compile `bibtex` and `pdflatex`?

Comment: see the manual of notepad: [Doc on command and shortcuts](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/commands)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I managed to find the perfect solution! For some reason, this didn't show up on my previous Google searches. I tailored my version of this solution: http://nimal.info/blog/2010/latex-on-windows-with-miktex-and-notepad/

My version (on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine) is as follows:

1. Download and install Basic MiKTeX 2.9 (32-bit)
2. Download and install SumatraPDF
3. Create a batch file `miktex_to_latex.bat` and place it anywhere

   - For easy location, place the batch file in the [Notepad++ installation Path]
4. Copy-paste the following into the batch file and save it

   ```
   :: Called from Notepad++ Run  
   :: [path_to_bat_file] "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(NAME_PART)"  

   :: Change Drive and  to File Directory  
   %~d1  
   cd %1

   :: Run Cleanup  
   call:cleanup  

   :: Run pdflatex -&gt; bibtex -&gt; pdflatex -&gt; pdflatex  
   pdflatex %2  
   bibtex  %2  
   :: If you are using multibib the following will run bibtex on all aux files  
   :: FOR /R . %%G IN (*.aux) DO bibtex %%G  
   pdflatex %2  
   pdflatex %2  

   :: Run Cleanup  
   call:cleanup  

   :: Open PDF  
   START "" "C:\Progra~2\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" %3 -reuse-instance  

   :: Cleanup Function  
   :cleanup  
   del *.dvi
   del *.out
   :: del *.log 
   :: del *.aux  
   :: del *.bbl    
   :: del *.blg  
   :: del *.brf  

   goto:eof
   ```
5. Take care of the following:

   - All lines beginning with double colon `::` are comments
   - the `START` command should have the installation path of SumatraPDF
   - Make sure there are NO spaces in the path (Use `Progra~2`, not `Program Files (X86)`)
   - The `-reuse-instance` allows us to edit and recompile without quitting the PDF
6. Download (if it does not already exist) the [**NppExec**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/) plugin and place the `.dll` file in [Notepad++ installation path]\plugins
7. Open a `.tex` file in Notepad++, click on <kbd>F6</kbd> to execute
8. Type the following lines in the window that pops up:

   ```
   NPP_SAVE
   "<Path_to_bat_file>" "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(NAME_PART)" "$(NAME_PART).pdf"
   ```

   In my case, this is:

   ```
   NPP_SAVE
   "C:\Progra~2\Notepad++\miktex_to_latex.bat" "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(NAME_PART)" "$(NAME_PART).pdf"
   ```

   The above lines basically tell NppExec to "save the current `.tex` file, run the batch file, store results in current directory and name it the same as the `.tex` file"
9. Click on "Save" and type in a recognizable name such as 'PDFLaTex'
10. Go to the menubar, Plugins -> NppExec -> Advanced Options.. Under 'Menu item', choose the script we just created above, and 'Add/Modify' it to the Menu items with a suitable name. This allows us to assign shortcut keys through Settings -> Shortcut Mapper -> Plugin commands
11. Navigate to the script name and choose any shortcut key like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
12. Press the shortcut key <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to save and compile the `.tex` file. The SumatraPDF window should pop up and show the compiled PDF. Changes can be made and the file recompiled **without having to close the PDF**.

The BEST parts about this method are:

- There is no need to keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save and then compile to PDF. Everything is done in one key press!
- There is no need to keep closing the opened PDF and reopening it on recompiling (as in the case with Adobe Reader)
- It is very easy to cleanup all the junk files generated
- It is **completely open-source** and can be easily integrated with an existing Notepad++ installation

Thanks Nimal, Jonas, Bert and the others who contributed to this awesome solution!

Comment: be careful using the cleanup! any document that uses the information in the .aux will struggle if it is deleted every time. just try putting in one \ref to a \label and you'll see what i mean. Personally, I would recommend creating the `cleanup` file as a *separate* batch file, and calling it separately

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks a lot, I'll keep that in mind. Is it only the .aux that I should be worried about? I'm pretty sure that PDFLaTex doesn't use the dvi file as that is an intermediate file. I'm guessing the .out file and the likes are also not that useful. Would it make sense to keep the .aux and delete the rest instead of calling the cleanup batch file separately?

Comment: The `.bbl` files and friends are used by `biblatex`; you are correct about the `.dvi` files. I would seriously consider not deleting any of them until the document is finished, and just run your `cleanup` file at the end. The `del` command can be made to work recursively through your home directory, so you only need to run it once

Comment: Sure, that sounds fine. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I updated the steps to include an autosave option. Much more convenient!

Comment: This can be greatly simplified by using latexmk.

Comment: You might want to suppress the output of Notepad++ of the log file to show only errors and warnings and perhaps highlight them. For this, see http://johnbruer.com/2013/05/21/latex-editing-using-notepad/#note-10

Comment: @prrao Is there a way to run this even for files with dots in the file names ? Right now, the pdf generated gets renamed and thus does not open after compilation. Thanks for this method.

Comment: Also maybe useful: `NPP_CONSOLE 0` in the end for suppresing NppExec console if compilation is successful, `pdflatex ... -aux-directory "%TEMP%"` for creating files in temporary directory.

Comment: what if I want to use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`? I replaced it but it seems it takes long time to compare (compared with other tools)

Comment: @Trefex : can you elaborate ? I'd like to use `latexmk`…

Comment: @Carg latexmk will figure out by itself how many runs it has to perform, so usually, once latexmk is properly configure, you won't have to write your own custom script which will re-compile everytime 3 times etc...

Comment: @Trefex Actually, I already use latexmk to compile. But how can I use it from Notepad++ ? Should I use NPPExec ? Thanks

Comment: @Carg probably yes. I was more referring to that part in my comment rather than the notepad++ connection. That's also why I didn't make it an answer :)

Comment: On Windows 10, you might have to add the `pdflatex` and `bibtex` file path to the [**user environment varaibles**](https://superuser.com/questions/625222/batch-file-gives-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-but-commands-run-fi/1211133#1211133)

Comment: NOTE -reuse-instance for SumatraPDF has been long time depreciated Tabs mode is needed and -reuse-instance is REPLACED  by ReuseInstance = true  IN SumatraPDF-settings.txt (advanced options)

Comment: In the current version Notepad++ 7.8.9, it is possible to download NPPExec Plugin by selecting Plugins->Plugins Admin and selecting the said plugin. By clicking install this plugin is automatically installed.

Comment: for I don't know what reason is not working for me, @prrao I'm using v7.9.2

Answer (score 13):

I've stumbled through a bunch of different IDE's and honestly I think that notepad++ is one of the most underrated options available to anyone doing TeX stuff.

Along that line, I think that most of these other options, which I started with, are overly complicated when we have tools like `arara` and `latexmk`.  They all work fabulously well, and I greatly appreciate the help they have given me, but I think we should use all the tools available to us.  I personally love `arara` and I have my way that I now use every day that leans on `arara` more than notepad++.

This is my notepad++ set up in NppExec

```
NPP_SAVEALL
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
arara $(NAME_PART)
```

No batch files necessary.  In my documents, I usually use a variation on this set of rules.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on, shell: off }
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on, shell: off }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on, shell: off }
% arara: clean: { files: [ foo.log, foo.aux, foo.bbl, foo.blg, foo.log, foo.run.xml,  foo-blx.bib, foo.bcf, foo.out ] }
% arara: sumatrapdf
```

The `pdflatex`,`biber` and `clean` are all included in `arara`. `sumatrapdf` is mine, but is exceedingly simple.  `arara` also supplies a `bibtex` rule which is just as simple to call, but I prefer biber.

**`sumatrapdf.yaml`**

```
!config
# SumatraPDF rule for arara
# Author: Mr Komandez
identifier: sumatrapdf
name: SumatraPDF
commands: 
- <arara> DIRECTORY/sumatra.bat "@{getBasename(file)}.pdf" "@{options}"
arguments:
- identifier: options
flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
```

**`sumatra.bat`**

```
START /b "C:\Progra~2\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" %1 -reuse-instance  %2
EXIT
```

This way, **from the source code** you can change your compilation options on the fly, but your actual compilation can stay key-bound the same way.

Comment: NOTE -reuse-instance for SumatraPDF has been long time depreciated Tabs mode is needed and -reuse-instance is REPLACED  by ReuseInstance = true  IN SumatraPDF-settings.txt (advanced options)

Comment: Underrated is this answer! In my opinion, this is **the** answer. I saw it years ago and that was how I got to know `arara`, which I always use ever since.
I created an account in StackExchange and worked my reputation up so that I could upvote this answer and post this comment. Thank you very much!

Comment: For future users that come across this answer, the syntax in @mark-mendoza's sumatrapdf.yaml has been deprecated in newer versions of `arara` (see https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#removed)

Comment: You need to change both the "commands" key and the "flag" key. See examples of rules in the arara installation folder and https://islandoftex.gitlab.io/arara/manual/concepts/#rules.

Comment: I am getting this ERROR MSG (and does not open sumatra after successful compilation): `com.charleskorn.kaml.IncorrectTypeException at commands[0] on
line 7, column 3: Expected an object, but got a scalar value`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

This would be a comment, but for length.  I contributed to the batch file above, but here's my latest version:

```
:: Called from Notepad++ Run
:: [path_to_bat_file] "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(NAME_PART)"

:: Change Drive and  to File Directory
%~d1
cd %1

:: Run Cleanup
call:cleanup

:: Run pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex
pdflatex %2
bibtex  %2
:: If you are using multibib the following will run bibtex on all aux files
:: FOR /R . %%G IN (*.aux) DO bibtex %%G
pdflatex %2
pdflatex %2


:: Open PDF (Script updated based on comments by 'menfeser'
:: START "" "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" %2.pdf
if (%3)==() goto cleanup
::START "" %2.pdf
set str=%date%_%time%
set str=%str:/=-%
set str=%str::=-%
set str=%str: =_%
ren %2.pdf %2_%str%.pdf
"C:\Program Files\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe" %2_%str%.pdf

:: Cleanup Function
if %3==noclean goto eof
:cleanup
del *.log
del *.dvi
del *.aux
del *.bbl
del *.blg
del *.brf
del *.out
:eof
```

It's called with 3 parameters - directory, filename, and a third, which can be "noclean" to keep temp files, blank to clean up but not view pdf, and anything else to show the pdf.  I map [shift]+F5 to view and clean, and [ctrl]+F5 to view without cleaning.

As there's currently no windows pdf viewer that doesn't lock the file on opening (my original reason for preferring foxit) the batch file renames the output pdf to put a date/time stamp in the file *name* before opening, allowing the next build to be opened without errors.

Another macro to call ASpell is handy as well.

Comment: Doesn't SumatraPDF have a 32-bit Windows version? It doesn't lock the PDF on opening so LaTeX can definitely update it dynamically

Comment: I think there is, I rather liked the way foxit reopens in a new tab, keeping the previous copy open, so I fixed the batch file rather than installing something else.

Comment: SumatraPDF will open without locking the files in tabs for each separate compiled PDF

Answer (score 2):

As [mr-komandez](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/30184/mr-komandez) mentioned, there is also [latexmk](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk). It can completely automate the process for you. One of the coolest features of this package is the `-pvc`-switch, which provides a continuous mode. So every time you save a file in the workspace, latexmk will run the necessary toolchain to compile. It has a lot of options, but for bibtex/pdflatex you can do this (assuming you have the [NppExec](https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec) plugin set up):

#### Setup Notepad++ with NppExec

1. Open Notepad++
2. Go to Plugins -> NppExec -> Execute... *(or press F6)*.
3. Type the following in the `Commands(s)` textfield:

**NppExec Command (with `-pvc` switch)**

```
NPP_SAVE 
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
latexmk -pvc -pdf -latex=pdflatex -latexoption="-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder" -bibtex main.tex
```

4. Press the save button and give it a good name.
5. NppExec will immediately execute and if you have the console open (toggle it with `ctrl+~`), you can see any errors in the compile log.

**NppExec Command (without `-pvc` switch)**
If you want more control over things like cleaning directories on some runs, use different engines (such as xelatex) or for some reason you do not like to have `-pvc` doing its thing. You can also setup NppExec with hotkeys and amend the above with anything specified in the [latexmk manual](http://ctan.uib.no/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf), there are quite the repertoire of options and switches you can use. If you follow the steps above, remove the `-pvc` and make any changes you see fit, you can then use the saved commands in the following way:

1. In Notepad++, go to Plugins -> NppExec -> Advanced Options.
2. In the window that pops up, you can see `Associated Scripts" at the bottom left.
3. Select the saved script, from here you can add hotkeys to different runs for ease of access.

[image: NppExec Advanced Options]

### A last note

Since you are using MiKTeX, you can also use the `-aux-dir=` & `-outdir=`-switches, which will put all auxiliary files/compiled files in subfolders as specified.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my contribution for configuring Notepad++ with NPP EXEC (v.7.9.2 -32bit) using just a part from @Mark Mendoza:

If you already installed `arara` and is working use

in NPP EXEC (F6) add the following:

```
NPP_SAVE
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
arara -v $(NAME_PART)
npp_run  "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).pdf"
```

after compiling it will pop-up the `.pdf`. I'm using Sumatra PDF with Advanced Option: `ReuseInstance = true`