# How to navigate TeXnicCenter  documents

Tags: texniccenter

I use TeXnicCenter to write my LaTeX documents and usually have big files open; I navigate up and down extensively.

For example, I am writing something, I move to the beginning of the document to take some label or read something I wrote, and then I go down again to continue writing.

This entire process is very tedious, and I am looking for something like the code navigation arrows that you have in eclipse to navigate through the point in the code you are editing.

Does anybody know any useful command?
I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> that brings me to the last point I was editing, but this not enough.

Comment: This is just an opinion... TeXNiCCenter is a good editor to get started on, but once you crave navigation, it is pretty limited- it sounds like you're ready to move on to more advanced editors... [notepad++](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43984/using-notepad-with-miktex-on-windows) would be an upgrade, but even better (imho) would be `vim`

Comment: If you know Eclipse well, perhaps [Texlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/) is of interest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to set a bookmark and <kbd>F2</kbd> (foreward) or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (backward) to go to the next bookmark? You can set more than one bookmark.
Just set your cursor to a second line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. For each bookmark you will see a little blue rectangle in the line numbering. You can also open window showing all bookmarks: point in a free place after the title line of window, click left and choose (I suppose it is) bookmarks (I'm using a german version). You can unset all bookmarks with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or only the choosen with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

In version 1 of TeXnicCenter one could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> to set numbered bookmarks (<kbd>number</kbd> has to be between 0 and 9). In version 2 that is not possible.

Comment: +1, How do you set the second bookmark so that it doesn't override the first? (Or, asking the other way round, how do you override the first?)