# Texniccenter 2: numbered bookmarks

Tags: editors, texniccenter

In Texniccenter 1, there were numbered bookmarks set with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>.

In Texniccenter 2, this extremely useful command was removed.

Can I somehow get back, or emulate, this functionality?

As a side note: in Texniccenter 1, you could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to go to the place where the document was last changed. In Texniccenter 2, the hotkey was changed to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>.

Comment: Generic bookmarks can be set using Ctrl + F2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TeXnicCenter version 2.x the developers changed the keys.  The numbers are gone, but they replaced this functionality with other keys.

I answered this already here: [How to navigate TeXnicCenter  documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63848/how-to-navigate-texniccenter-documents/63955#63955)

So you do not need to emulate them, only the keys have changed ...

If you want the old keys back you can ask the support of TeXnicCenter to do that but I think you will not be lucky ...

Comment: Thank you! But this is no replacement for the version 1 way: in version 1, you could set ten bookmarks and when you needed 8th of them, jump directly to it. In the "improved" version, you need to cicle through all bookmarks, at each one understand what it is and decide whether this is the one that you are looking for. After fifth iteration of this process you will forget what you are looking for and where you was before you interrupted your writing and started looking for a bookmark. Next time you will not want to do it. So the question is: any workaround other than junking TeXnicCenter?