# work on documents on Linux and Windows (umlaut, newline)

Tags: texniccenter, linux, workflow

We work on a latex document with three persons using emacs on linux, emacs on windows and texniccenter on windows. We encountered problems with umlauts and linebreaks. I would like to know:

- We should probably use utf8 encoding. Can I tell Texniccenter or other "easy to use" Latex editors on windows to use utf8 and keep a unix-formatted file (concerning linebreak) in that format?
- Are there general recommendations for this problem?

Comment: I think that Texmaker or TeXStudio are what you're looking for; they are multiplatform, so you can have the same environment on both systems.

Comment: More generally, there are many IDEs which can do this: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: As for the _other "easy" to use editors_, although not latex specific, it is worth mentioning notepad++. It is a free windows editor for plain text or coding, with some advanced features such as syntax highligting, folding, autoindent, etc. And of course it can read utf8 and unix linefeeds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beside the suggestion of a multi platform TeX editor: If the Windows user insisted on TeXnicCenter, he/she should use the quite new TeXnicCenter 2.0 Beta1 (TXC below) – for download go to http://www.texniccenter.org/ –, then all of your requirements would be satisfied:

- It is UTF8-aware.
- It can read files with UNIX line endings (i.e. bare line feeds).

Both is indicated on the status bar, what must be activated, of course (in menu “View”):

[image: statusbar excerpt]

The TXC user could set up the following: Under menu “Tools” –> “Options” –> “Files” –> “Default” he/she could also change the default line ending for newly created files to UNIX style:

[image: TXC options menu]

Converting between ending formats and also between charsets can in TXC only be done, when one uses the “Save As” or “Save Copy As” dialogues:

[image: “Save as” dialogue]

Also a general text editor could be used for this purpose. There is a bunch of good text editors for Windows out there also with TeX syntax highlighting and possibility of converting, one of them was mentioned here several times, see an example in [Using Notepad++ with MiKTeX on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43984/using-notepad-with-miktex-on-windows) and the respective entry under [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10220).