# How to change the text encoding of a TeXnicCenter project?

Tags: texniccenter, input-encodings

I was trying to collaborate with another person on a LaTeX project. Unfortunately we have a text encoding problem. He cant use my ANSI coded files. Now I need to change all my files to UTF8. Is there a option in TeXnicCenter for changing all files to utf8 or need I do it manually by saving and renaming files?

Comment: Though your question is a bit different, my answer applies to it: [work on documents on Linux and Windows (umlaut, newline)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96556/9237).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you have to open all your files you have to change to code utf8. Then save them with the same name (easier to do), just change the encoding with the shown encoding listbox.

A remark: if possible (if all used packages support utf8) use always file encoding utf8. It makes communication with other much more easier ...

It could be a good idea to make a feature request on the homepage of TeXnicCenter (http://www.texniccenter.org) to add such a general encoding changing.

Perhaps this question [batch change encoding ascii files from utf8 to iso 8859-1](https://superuser.com/questions/69091/batch-change-encoding-ascii-files-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1) can give you a hint to do it without TeXnicCenter.