# unicode char causing troubles within subfiles

Tags: unicode

I have an issue that only happens when I try to sepparate my latex code in many subfiles. If I let all the "special characters" in the main file, there's no problem, but
if I move them to a subfile and then import it. It cannot compile because of an error described by the compiler as:

```
 pdflatex> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ícl not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

This is a minimal example that works:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    cíclico
\end{document}
```

This is a minimal example that doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \input{file1.tex}
\end{document}
```

Where file1.tex only contains:

```
cíclico
```

Comment: Well, the problem was my IDE (TeXnicCenter) it was saving the files with an encoding different from utf8. What I did and worked is, delete the "subfiles" create them again with TexMaker, save them and then it compiled without problems. So now, my question is reduced to this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99887/how-to-change-the-text-encoding-of-a-texniccenter-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem was my IDE (TeXnicCenter) along with my OS (Windows 8). TeXNicCenter was saving the files with an encoding different from utf8. What I did and worked is, delete the "subfiles" create them again with TexMaker, save them and then it compiled without problems. So now, my question is reduced to this one:
[How to change the text encoding of a TeXnicCenter project?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99887/how-to-change-the-text-encoding-of-a-texniccenter-project)