# How to change encoding in TeXnicCenter 2.0?

Tags: texniccenter, input-encodings

It is not a duplicate of [How do I change the encoding of my files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19427/how-do-i-change-the-encoding-of-my-files) or [How to change the text encoding of a TeXnicCenter project?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99887/how-to-change-the-text-encoding-of-a-texniccenter-project). I haven't found an answer there.

Is there any possibility of changing the input encoding in TeXnicCenter 2.0? The logic of this editor was always strange for me, but now I am completely lost.

Comment: File > Save As... > [Choose your encoding](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ei3Yx.png)

Comment: +1 Thank you for a white stick in the jungle of TeXnicCenter!

Comment: I know this is hard to find (I’ve written this and had to struggle), but see the end of my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96556/9237 ;-)

Comment: @Speravir Thank you for a link. Hard to find, indeed. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File > Save As... > Choose your encoding:

[image]

The file encoding will be displayed in the bottom status bar.