# Accented letters in french

Tags: xetex, accents, polyglossia

I have experienced problems with the following

- Polyglossia
- xelatex
- fontspec

does not recognize accented letters in french

i'm using [Texniccenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/) as editor of tex with the latest update to my MIKTEX

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Scheherazade}

\newcommand{\setcontext}[2]{\setcounter{chapter}{#1}\setcounter{section}{#2}}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\mathopen{}\mathrm{d}}
%\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}

\newtheoremstyle{examplestyle}{10mm}{10mm}{\slshape}{2pt}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{examplestyle}
\makeatletter

\newcounter{descriptcount}
\newlist{enumdescript}{description}{2}
\setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\Roman{descriptcount}}}
  ,font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount~
}
\setlist[enumdescript,2]{%
  before={\setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
          \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\alph{descriptcount}}}
  ,font=\bfseries\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount~
}

\begin{document}


un âne, la grêle, un traîneau, un symptôme, une mûre
\begin{enumdescript}
   \item [L'accent  aigu]
    \
    \begin{itemize}[font=\color{magenta} , label=\ding{59}]
\item amitié - tenacité - prévenir - médecin;
\end{itemize}
\item [L'accent grave]
\
    \begin{itemize}[font=\color{magenta} , label=\ding{59}]
\item  abcès - enlèvement - exprès - grève
\end{itemize}
\end{enumdescript}
\end{document}
```

which produces 
[image]

there is no error tex just warning in my techniccenter :

```
%%
%% This is file `fontspec-patches.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% fontspec.dtx  (with options: `patches')
%% 
%%   _________________________________________
%%   The fontspec package for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
%%   (C) 2004--2014    Will Robertson and Khaled Hosny
%% 
%%   License information appended.
%% 
%% 
\ProvidesPackage{fontspec-patches}
  [2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX]


\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \@fnsymbol #1
 {
  \int_case:nnF {#1}
   {
    {0} {}
    {1} { \mode_if_math:TF *\textasteriskcentered }
    {2} { \mode_if_math:TF \dagger\textdagger }
    {3} { \mode_if_math:TF \ddagger\textdaggerdbl }
    {4} { \mode_if_math:TF \mathsection\textsection }
    {5} { \mode_if_math:TF \mathparagraph\textparagraph }
    {6} { \mode_if_math:TF \|\textbardbl }
    {7} { \mode_if_math:TF {**}{\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered} }
    {8} { \mode_if_math:TF {\dagger\dagger}{\textdagger\textdagger} }
    {9} { \mode_if_math:TF {\ddagger\ddagger}{\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl} }
   }
   { \@ctrerr }
 }
\DeclareRobustCommand \em
 {
  \@nomath\em
  \str_if_eq_x:nnTF \f@shape \itdefault \eminnershape
  {
    \str_if_eq_x:nnTF \f@shape \sldefault \eminnershape \emshape
  }
 }
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\em}
\cs_set_eq:NN \emshape \itshape
\cs_set_eq:NN \eminnershape \upshape
\DeclareRobustCommand{\-}
 {
  \discretionary
   {
    \char\ifnum\hyphenchar\font<\z@
           \xlx@defaulthyphenchar
         \else
           \hyphenchar\font
         \fi
   }{}{}
 }
\def\xlx@defaulthyphenchar{`\-}
\cs_new:Nn \fontspec_visible_space:
 {
  \font_glyph_if_exist:NnTF \font {"2423}
   { \char"2423\scan_stop: }
   { \fontspec_visible_space_fallback: }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \fontspec_visible_space_fallback:
 {
  {
   \usefont{\g_fontspec_encoding_tl}{lmtt}{\f@series}{\f@shape}
   \textvisiblespace
  }
 }
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:n{"20}%
\cs_gset:Npn\fontspec_print_visible_spaces:{%
\char_set_catcode_active:n{"20}%
\cs_set_eq:NN^^20\fontspec_visible_space:%
}%
\group_end:
\def\verb
 {
  \relax\ifmmode\hbox\else\leavevmode\null\fi
  \bgroup
    \verb@eol@error \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
    \verbatim@font\@noligs
    \@ifstar\__fontspecsverb\@verb
 }
\def\__fontspecsverb{\fontspec_print_visible_spaces:\@sverb}
\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \fontspec_patch_verbatim:
  \fontspec_patch_moreverb:
  \fontspec_patch_fancyvrb:
  \fontspec_patch_listings:
 }
\cs_set:Npn \fontspec_patch_verbatim:
 {
  \@ifpackageloaded{verbatim}
   {
    \cs_set:cpn {verbatim*}
     {
      \group_begin: \@verbatim \fontspec_print_visible_spaces: \verbatim@start
     }
   }
   {
    \cs_set:cpn {verbatim*}
     {
      \@verbatim \fontspec_print_visible_spaces: \@sxverbatim
     }
   }
 }
\cs_set:Npn \fontspec_patch_moreverb:
 {
  \@ifpackageloaded{moreverb}{
    \cs_set:cpn {listingcont*}
     {
      \cs_set:Npn \verbatim@processline
       {
        \thelisting@line \global\advance\listing@line\c_one
        \the\verbatim@line\par
       }
      \@verbatim \fontspec_print_visible_spaces: \verbatim@start
     }
  }{}
 }
\cs_set:Npn \fontspec_patch_fancyvrb:
 {
  \@ifpackageloaded{fancyvrb}
   {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \FancyVerbSpace \fontspec_visible_space:
   }{}
 }
\cs_set:Npn \fontspec_patch_listings:
 {
  \@ifpackageloaded{listings}
   {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \lst@visiblespace \fontspec_visible_space:
   }{}
 }
\RenewDocumentCommand \oldstylenums {m}
 {
  { \addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyle} #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand \liningnums {m}
 {
  { \addfontfeature{Numbers=Lining} #1 }
 }
%% 
%% Copyright 2004--2014 Will Robertson <wspr81@gmail.com>
%% Copyright 2009--2013   Khaled Hosny <khaledhosny@eglug.org>
%% 
%% Distributable under the LaTeX Project Public License,
%% version 1.3c or higher (your choice). The latest version of
%% this license is at: http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%% This work is "maintained" by Will Robertson.
%% 
%% This work consists of this file fontspec.dtx
%%           and the derived files fontspec.sty,
%%                                 fontspec.lua,
%%                                 fontspec.cfg,
%%                                 fontspec-xetex.sty,
%%                                 fontspec-luatex.sty,
%%                                 fontspec-patches.sty,
%%                                 fontspec-example.tex,
%%                             and fontspec.pdf.
%% 
%%
%% End of file `fontspec-patches.sty'.
```

my code works fine i already checked it here https://www.overleaf.com/2280649fdmwpj#/5853636/ the problem is with Texniccenter

Comment: If I compile the example, I can see the accented letters.

Comment: Your text editor is probably not set to UTF8 text encoding.

Comment: I also see the accented letters with your code (I'm using TeX Live2014).

Comment: i use techniccenter as editor of tex

Comment: I don't know TeXniccenter. Can it be configured to UTF-8 Unicode text encoding?

Comment: i don't know but may be see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99887/how-to-change-the-text-encoding-of-a-texniccenter-project and  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19427/how-do-i-change-the-encoding-of-my-files

Comment: @Educ: TeXnicCenter can be used to change the encoding, yes. In the bottom-right status bar you'll see the current encoding (ASCII, ANSI, UTF8, ...). To change it, File > Save As... > (choose correct encoding).

Comment: It doesn't seem to use utf8 by default.

Comment: @Werner In that case, the file encoding must fit the default encoding of TeXnicCenter. Since this one is a XeLaTeX file, I figure that TeXnicCenter's default encoding must be previously set to UTF8-Unicode if one wants to get the accents.

Comment: @Werner yes its works when i save it as utf8

Comment: My TeXnic Center endodes new files as `Ansi`: I suppose this is the default encoding, but the site claims it's `utf8`. A bug?

Comment: i think based on what i did to solve that problem is 'Ansi' even it showed 'UTF8'

Comment: Reading comments below I see that it was just a problem of the editor encoding configuration that was solved after using the right encoding. Do you want to provide an answer to your own question or do you consider we could close it?

Comment: Mr  Gonzalo Medina you can provide answer

Comment: Thanks but I think the person who should write an answer is @fpast who gave the clue about the editor encoding. Would you (fpast) like to provide a proper answer?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina  yes why not

Comment: @Educ I've just wrote this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of problems generally comes from the fact that the LaTeX editor is not configured to the suitable input encoding. In this peculiar case (a XeLaTeX file, and XeTeX interpreting the input as UTF-8 by default), it means that the editor must be configured to UTF8-Unicode input encoding.

Comment: Try this piece of code: \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [french]{babel}