# How to make sure that a source file is in UNIX mode?

Tags: winedt, ctan, unix

**How to make sure that a source file is in `UNIX` mode?**

In other words, how to check that every line in a text file is ended by LF rather then CR+LF? I am asking because a package intended for uploading to CTAN should be saved in `UNIX` mode. Earlier, it was possible to emulate `UNIX` mode in WinEdt, but after upgrading to `WinEdt 7` I don't see UNIX in a list of WinEdt's submodes.

P.S. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: I post-process files when making the zip file (`zip -r -q -X -ll` using InfoZIP): is that an option for you?

Comment: [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) can handle that. Both an indicator in the status bar, and a set of menus under `Edit / EOL Conversion`

Comment: @JosephWright, thank you, unfortunetely, most links to infozip (including Wikipwdia) are not active.

Comment: @Igor Probably the easiest way to install it as part of [GNU on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki).

Comment: @JosephWright, please transform your comment to answer.

Comment: For users of TeXnicCenter: [work on documents on Linux and Windows (umlaut, newline)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86704/work-on-documents-on-linux-and-windows-umlaut-newline)

Comment: You'd have to ask the current CTAN folks if this is still their preference but in the past we used the fact that unzip -a will give the files the correct line endings.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing has changed in WinEdt 7. Simply add :UNIX at the end of your document's mode in Document Settings dialog (accessible via the Document menu) and press OK.
Your document's EOL will be changed to LF.

Comment: Hi Karl Nice to see you here :-)

Answer (score 1):

This Answer won't help using windows, however:
The line breaker problem for users of Mac OSX can be solved by the linebreak application.
http://code.google.com/p/linebreak/ Works via drag and drop, takes presets or asks what todo.
Transfers Mac, Unix, and Windows/DOS formats in all directions. Can preserve original file.