# Biber error after MiKTeX update

Tags: errors, miktex, biber, updating

After having updated Biber from 1.5 version to 1.8, while the build time, I'm getting errors on the `\begin{document}` of my latex code telling that `File ended while scanning use of \field.`. I've tried to compile the same full code on [this site](https://www.sharelatex.com), and this have worked.

Knowing that I'm on Windows 7 SP1 and using MiKTeX 2.9, how do I to fix this please?

I've tried to use `Update (Admin)` of MiKTeX for updates, but, after doing this I still getting the same errors.

## [Full Log file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/20j7e7f27tr67vb/rapport.log).

## [Minimal Log file related to the below .tex code](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ds5ajleghx5b2t1/a.log).

.tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel} \usepackage{csquotes}% recommended in output (biblatex) 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{bibli.bib} 
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\end{document}
```

small .bib file

```
@online{msdn2,
    label    = {MSDN2},
    title    = {Comparatif entre C\# et Visual Basic .NET},
    author   = {Microsoft},
    date     = {2014-01-01},
    url      = {http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308470},
    urldate  = {2014-04-12}
}
```

Comment: Could you post a `.tex` file with an accompanying `.bib` file? Any `.log` or output, would be also useful to us debugging your problem. I remember that at some point Biber changed quite dramatically, so please post a MWE.

Comment: @gns-ank, I've updated my post

Comment: Well, even though the example is not quite minimal (certainly a lot of the packages and redefinitions could be removed), it works on my computer (MikTeX 2.9, newest `biblatex`, Biber [v 2.8/1.8 respectively]). Please be more specific on what error message you get and also post the (relevant passages of your) `.log` and `.blg` files.

Comment: As it already happpened to me I guess it's with the binary cache that Biber creates, getting corrupted on an update. The solution is to delete the cache directory, that is somewhere in your personal directory; on my WinXP system it is in C:\Documents and Settings\Bernard\Local Settings\Temp\par-4265726e617264. The important thing to find (and delete) is `\Temp\par-4265726e617264`.

You will find many details [on this thread.][1]


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file

Comment: Of course it goes without saying that the long sequence of figures and letter that follows `par-` may vary.

Comment: @Bernard, that wouldn't work :/ it still the same!

Comment: Did you try removing the `.bbl` file and recreating it running Biber?

Comment: @egreg, yes, I've tried to remove all of the output files.

Comment: Strange… I would have bet my life on it. Incidentally, on Win 7, the directory is in `C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4265726e617264`.

Comment: @Bernard, it still the same. Nothing have changed :/

Comment: @dgs: The only thing to do I can see in such a case is to delete again the binary cache directory, uninstall biber with the MiKTeX package manager, then re-install it.

Comment: @Bernard, I've did that but I still getting the same errors

Comment: @Bernard, would you please link me a good version of MiKTeX, I've installed the 64bits version. it's maybe due to that.

Comment: @dgs: I think I understand now. MiKTeX doesn't have a 64 bit version of biber. Here is what I did, as I also have the 64-bit version: I went on CTAN to MiKTeX packages repository and downloaded `miktex-biber-bin.tar.lzma` (that's a 32-bit version).I uncompressed it, obtaining a `texmf` directory. Then  I moved the  `contents` of this directory  (not the directory itself) in my Local TeXMF directory, as is. Next you'll have to refresh the FNDB as usual, and maybe install a perl distribution (I have Strawberry Perl). That's about all.

Comment: @Bernard, what have you installed as biber version?

Comment: @dgs: the 32-bit version as there's no other.

Comment: 1.8 biber version?

Comment: Yes. Look at @moewe's comment above. If there is only one `biber` for MiKTeX, moewe must be using that (32bit) version and says there that it is 1.8. (2.8 is the `biblatex` version which works with `biber` 1.8.)

Comment: @cfr, but how to upgrade biblatex?

Comment: Doesn't MiKTeX include `biblatex` at least?! The 32/64 bit thing is irrelevant here so I'd assume that having up-to-date MiKTeX would automatically take care of this.

Comment: I've 2.8a biblatex's version installed, but updating Biber hasn't solved my problem.

Comment: @moewe, [here is my log file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/20j7e7f27tr67vb/rapport.log).

Comment: @cfr, [here is my log file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/20j7e7f27tr67vb/rapport.log).

Comment: @gns-ank, [here is my log file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/20j7e7f27tr67vb/rapport.log).

Comment: I've updated my post linking the minimal log file. Can you please help to catch from where is coming the error?

Comment: @dgs You do not need to write your comments more than one time, especially where interested people can see your edit.

Comment: @dgs: I must second moewe: Your code is far from being a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), in fact I see some issues at least with `url` and `hyperref`, but nonetheless I also do not have any problem with compiling your code (note, that I have 32bit MiKTeX on a 64bit Windows 7).

Comment: @Speravir, have you found any ambigious line into the minimal posted log file?

Comment: @dgs Your `biblatex` is up to date. 2.8a is the correct version. When you run `biber` what version does it now report?

Comment: @cfr, 1.8 version.

Comment: @dgs: I just was going to comment that there is no other problem than that like stated you should run the compiling a second time. You must, of course have executed biber after first compiling run.

Comment: @Speravir, I do. I'm compiling the .tex file, then using biber command, and finally the .tex file (only at this time, I get 44 errors).

Comment: @dgs I think it would be good to use a completely minimal example, with a known good `.bib` file for testing. I've posted one below. Please try compiling it and post any errors in your question. Note that it is better to post logs etc. to a pastebin site so that people do not have to download an unknown entity to help you. (I won't do this basically - I doubt I'm alone in this.) With a really minimal case, though, it should be easy to post the errors in your question.

Comment: @cfr, I've just posted a minimal code.

Comment: @dgs: You should use a *really* minimal file to see if biber runs on your system or not. In your preamble the only necessary lines are the following: `\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}% recommended in output (biblatex)
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}` and `\addbibresource{otherbibli.bib}
\usepackage{titletoc}`. Comment out the rest of the preamble, compile and see what happens (hope you have a good editor that lets you comment out selected portions of text with a single click, or make a copy and delete the spurious lines).

Comment: @dgs: That one is really minimal, and it runs fine on my system. Does it now on yours?

Comment: @Bernard, No I'm now getting 118 errors.

Comment: @Bernard, Do I post the new log file?

Comment: @dgs What is the *first* error you get?

Comment: @cfr, `File ended while scanning use of \field.` on `\begin{document}`

Comment: Also after the edit with your real minimal code: No problem on my side.

Comment: @dgs: OK, but first change your inputenc to `utf8`, not cp1250, delete your auxiliary files ansd re-compile. Utf8 is the only encoding that is understood by all OSs and all modern editors use it by default. I'd like to see the .blg too.

Comment: @Bernard, using utf8 I get errors on this kind of words `Minist\\`ere`.

Comment: @dgs Where is `Minist\\`ere` in your example?

Comment: @cfr, it's in my main code.

Comment: @dgs: Why don't you type directly Ministère?

Comment: @Bernard, because doing that I get `Package inputenc Error:Unicde char \u8:ère not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Comment: @dgs But the whole point is to see if you can compile the minimal example without errors. The fact that you get errors when you compile your main code is, at this stage, simply irrelevant. I don't mean it isn't a problem. But it is not *the* problem we are concerned with *right now*. We cannot help if you will not run the tests because we do not have access to your computer. We have to rely on you to run those tests. Yet you keep posting errors from your main document when we haven't even figured out if you can compile a minimal one.

Comment: @dgs You never bothered to say whether you could compile the minimal document I posted. That would tell us whether there is a basic problem with your set up or a problem with your code. Right now we know absolutely nothing.

Comment: @cfr, Oh sorry! With the minimal code, I haven't get any error. but I was testing it on my main code here.

Comment: I've executed the minimal code using utf8 as suggested @Bernard and that works without any output error. But testing this on the main code, leads output errors.

Comment: @dgs OK! Good! Thank you! Now we know that `biber` is working OK. So we know it is installed correctly, it matches your `biblatex` version and that everything is being found OK at compile time. Now we know the problem is somewhere in your code. That is tremendously helpful. (Though I realise that you want your code to work but we are trying to narrow down the problem so ruling stuff out is progress.)

Comment: @cfr, no problem. Thank you too for your time. Do you need now me to repost the full premble code?

Comment: I could compile your minimal body file(just the bibliography)  with the whole preamble, jsut changing the input encoding. Are you sure you need every package loaded in the preamble?

Comment: @Bernard, yes I need them. But, how to fix utf8 to work on my main code (report) ?

Comment: @dgs: It depends. What was the initial encoding? If you know it you may try to convert (I think editors like TeXmaker or scite or notepad++ can do that), but there probably will remain  residual badly converted characters, often due to the fact that there are several encodings messed up in the document. In such a case you will usually be able to see to which character it corresponds, and then just do a search and replace for that character. It will take a certain time but it ceratinly is worth the time.

Comment: @Bernard, it was `cp1250`. I have also tried to load utf8x on the main project but this led me to much output errors, so I haven't used it. As editor text, I'm using TexnicCenter.

Comment: I don't if TeXnic Center can do that. I know TeXmaker can. My suggestion is to install it, at least. for the conversion. If you open your main file with it, it will warn that it is not utf8 encoded, but cp 1250, and ask you if you want to load the file with this encoding. Of course, say yes. Then go to the tools menu; the last item of this menu  is `Convert to Unicode`.

Comment: @Bernard, you may want to make an answer, this have finally worked. Thank you very much !!!

Comment: @cfr, THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!! This has finally worked :DD

Comment: @moewe, THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!! This has finally worked :DD

Comment: @gns-ank, THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!! This has finally worked :DD

Comment: @Speravir, THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!! This has finally worked :DD

Comment: ;) [I figure at this point *one* more comment can't hurt... can it?]

Comment: @dgs: I'm glad it worked… I don't know what answer I could make, as there was no specific question, except you couldn't compile.

Comment: @dgs: Would be good if you would write a short answer yourself about the reason and the cure. See also last part of my answer [work on documents on Linux and Windows (umlaut, newline)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96556) beginning from “Converting between ending formats” or more general [How do I change the encoding of my files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19427).

Comment: @dgs: And you should edit title and question to your real problem (with a short note that you’ve rewritten this).

Answer (score 2):

As the problem actually seems linked to the fact that MiKTeX 64-bit doesn't include biber, which is a 32-bit application, you should take a look at the answers to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63039/install-biber-in-miktex-on-a-64-bit-version-of-windows). Don't forget to create a Local TeXMF root if you don't already have one.

**Added on 09/20/2015:**

Since last summer, MiKTeX 64bits repositories have a `miktex-bin-biber-x64.tar.lzma` file, so the above-mentioned answers are obsolete. Install biber through MiKTeX Package Manager.

Comment: Please post this as a comment and not as an answer. If this solves the OP's problem, you can then post it as an answer. But from what we know now it might well be an entirely different problem.

Comment: @Bernard, I've downloaded and installed the [32-bits version of MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/2.9/setup) which is placed at the first place in the link. And downloaded [thr 1.7 biber version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/1.7/binaries/Windows/) and pasted the exe file under `C:/../miktex/bin/` but this wouldn't work. I've also tried [the 1.8 version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/1.8/binaries/Windows/), but it still the same.

Comment: Did you refresh the FNDB? Did you put it in a *local* texmf root? And did you declare this local root via `MiKTeX Settings`( `Roots` tab)?

Comment: what's the mean of `FNDB` ?

Comment: Yes, I've putted the `biber.exe` file under `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\`.

Comment: File Names Data Base. MiKTeX uses this database to find all sorts of files (executable, .config, .sty, .cls, &c.) So if biber is not in the database, it won't be found. Don't forget you also have to declare the new root. I think you'd better name it differently because that root is the one used by the 32-bit version of MiKTeX. It might be confusional.

Comment: @dgs: 1) When you open the MiKTeX settings you will see under the General tab a button “Refresh FNDB”. 2) Please, do not install into main MiKTeX installation, cf. [Install Biber in MiKTeX on a 64-bit version of Windows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167324) and linked answers and comments.

Comment: @Speravir, but I can not open `miktex-biber-bin.tar.lzma` from Windows 7 !

Comment: When I paste the biber.exe under `c:/../miktex/bin/` and run the biber command, biber tells its version at compile time. And that worked (its update), why this can't be solve the problem ?

Comment: @dgs: You need a file archiver that can handle LZMA compressed files, e.g. [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or [PeaZip](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/). Why you shouldn’t install in main installation: See [Purpose of local texmf trees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69487).

Comment: @Bernard, please how to declare this local root via MiKTeX Settings( Roots tab)?

Comment: @Speravir, please how to declare this local root via MiKTeX Settings( Roots tab)?

Comment: @dgs: Well, it’s alreay linked in questions and answer we gave you as hint, but see [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483).

Comment: @Speravir, thank you very much! I've just installed biber's 1.2 version like you've described, after compiling my report I haven't got any error, but when I've displayed the PDF file, I've found the bibliography. After that, I've upgraded biber to 1.8 using MiKTeX package manager and compiled the report again and I've got the same errors.

Comment: @Speravir, [here is my log file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/20j7e7f27tr67vb/rapport.log).

Comment: @Bernard, [here is my log file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/20j7e7f27tr67vb/rapport.log).

Comment: @dgs: Well there are quite a number of errors that don't seem to have anything to do with biber or biblatex. You should try to run a minimalistic file, just containing a call to a simple .bib file to see if biber works ot not.

Comment: @Bernard, I've updated my post linking the minimal log file.

Comment: You might want to mention that as of now there is a version of Biber for 64-bit MikTeX, so people don't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Biber have implied that I must encode my report on UTF8.

Thanks to @Bernard, @cfr, @Speravir, @moewe and @gns_ank.