# Output latexindent auxiliary files to a different directory

Tags: auxiliary-files, latexindent

I just started using Notepad++ and SumatraPDF for my LaTeX stuff.

When compiling a `.tex` file using `pdflatex`, one can specify an option `-output-directory=<folder>` to save all the auxiliary files in `<folder>`. Is there a way to make [`latexindent`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexindent) do something similar? That is, when I run `latexindent.pl -w foo.tex`, I want it save the backup and log files in a folder that I specify.

Comment: BTW, here's a nice guide in setting up Notepad++ to run `pdflatex`: [LaTeX Editing Using Notepad++](http://johnbruer.com/2013/05/21/latex-editing-using-notepad/), besides of course this one on TeX.SX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43984/using-notepad-with-miktex-on-windows

Comment: *(As the author)* Thanks for trying `latexindent`! That's a great idea; it's not currently possible, but I'll add it to the to-do list. Presumably you would want to specify the settings in a `yaml` file with switches (something like): `backupDirectory: /my/output/directory` and `logfileDirectory: /some/other/directory`?

Comment: @cmhughes: Thank *you* for writing such a nice script! Ideally I'd like to have a switch that does exactly what `-output-directory=<folder>` does in `pdflatex`; for example, as in `latexindent.pl -w  -output-directory=<path to folder> foo.tex`. I suppose this will imply a change in the `.pl` file (but I'm not sure). Settings in a `yaml` file would imply that *all* backup and log files will be saved in those same folder(s) regardless of where `foo.tex` was initially saved, right?

Comment: There are a few different `yaml` files- you have `defaultSettings.yaml`, and then your own files which can reside anywhere; in particular, you can have `localSettings.yaml` which overrides anything else. Most of the script's behaviour is controlled from `yaml`, so my first instinct is to put it in there. I hope to get to the to-do list at some point soon....

Comment: @cmhughes: Thanks! I'm looking forward to the next update in `latexindent` `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version ([available on github](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.plx)) contains a switch, `-c=/path/to/cruft/directory` that performs in the way you described. You can use it as follows, for example

```
latexindent.pl -w -c=/home/cmhughes/Desktop myfile.tex
```

which will output all of the 'cruft' (`indent.log`, `myfile.bak*`) to `/home/cmhughes/Desktop`. It performs a check to make sure that the directory exists- if it doesn't, then the script will exit.

I did think about implementing this in the `yaml` files, but since `indent.log` writes information about the contents of these files, I found myself going round in circles. As such, the suggestion to use a command line switch makes the most sense.

I have also updated the [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara) rule which can be used as, for example,

```
% arara: indent: { cruft: /home/cmhughes/Desktop }
```

I have found the `arara` rule does not like it when the directories contain spaces (but the command line version doesn't mind).

Comment: I'm making a few more changes today and tomorrow, and then I'll get the new version uploaded to `ctan`, which will hopefully get included into `texlive`

Comment: @jfbu thanks for the follow-up :) It was clear that my 'answer' needed a lot of work, so I thought it was just easier simply to delete it. Feel free to post your own answer, I'm sure it'd receive some votes