# How do I use Notepad++ with MiKTeX and Sumatrapdf

Tags: miktex, sumatrapdf

This identical question has been answered, but unfortunately the answer is a bit over my head :( EDIT: way over my head.

I need a **very basic** explanation - preferably in English not computersciencese - for how to do this. Things I don't understand from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43984/using-notepad-with-miktex-on-windows) and [here](http://nimal.info/blog/2010/latex-on-windows-with-miktex-and-notepad/) are:

1. What is a batch file, should I just copy the code (which is Greek to me) directly in or might I need to modify it, and what is a path/how do I put the batch file in the path to Notepad++
2. What is that "NPPExec" plugin, what is a dll file, and why do or do not I need it? And if I need it, what do I do with it and where do I get it?
3. For those of you familiar with Notepad++, how do I create these keyboard shortcuts that everyone is saying to create?

Thank you all in advance, I have already made much progress in LaTeX, largely because of the help from this site. Slowly but surely!

Comment: Notepad++ is a very good general editor, with syntax highlighting for many programming languages (including TeX), but I think you should stick with a dedicated editor, which will be much more helpful. That said, a batch file is a commands program (a shell script) for Windows, with a special syntax. You even can run latex from the command line, but nobody does that except in very special cases. For explanations on `dll`s take a look at this page: http://www.easydesksoftware.com/dll.htm

Comment: Does TeXworks count as an editor? Should I even bother with configuring Notepad++ to use for TeX? And I'm really not looking for anything fancy. Running from command line would be fine with me - if I knew how :)

Comment: TeXworks is editor; Notepad is an editor, as Notepad++. You can use them all to type a .tex file. But some have more facilites tha others. A simple example: you *very* often have to type arguments between { }. In Notepad, you'll have to type first `{`, the your argument  and finally not forget to type the closing `}`, otherwise the compiler will scream. In a good editer, you'll have a shortcut such as `Ctrl+{`, and you'll have at once the pair `{}` and the cursor in between, just waiting you type your argument.  So unless you love typing again and again…

Comment: I think I can handle the brackets :) I guess I'll use TeXworks until I get notepad++ figured out for now.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend TeXworks until you run up against some limitations. It's more or less the least-common-denominator editor that everyone has, and it's certainly the simplest. In its Help menu, you'll find an entry labeled "A short manual for TeXworks", also available [at this link](https://texworks.googlecode.com/files/TeXworks-manual-r1029.pdf). Skim over chapters 1 and 2, and start reading more closely in chapter 3.

Comment: Well actually you can try also with `TeXMaker` is another dedicated editor with friendly inerface for `TeX' or `TeXStudio`an fork from the firs with few facilities for beginners.

Comment: @Bernard Notepad++ automatically types `{}` when you type `{`, with the latest version anyway.