# Custom Build to make glossaries with LaTeX using Sublime Text and LaTeXTools

Tags: pdftex

I recently moved from Notepad++ to Sublime Text for creating documents with LaTeX. I use LaTeXTools. However, I am unable to run the `makeindex` command with the associated parameters (`makeindex %.idx %.glo -t %.glg -s %.ist -o %.gls %.acn`) to produce glossaries (Glossaries, Acronyms, Symbols, etc). The documentation of [LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/tree/mbuilder) says that a custom builder has to be written to achieve this. I have read the documentation over and over but to be honest, I don't know how to go about this! I'm okay with the traditional builder using `texify` ... this correctly created the `bibliography` but unfortunately not the `glossaries`! Could someone be of help in pointing out how to go about writing a custom builder to enable me create the glossaries along side the bibliography?

PS: I can well produce the glossaries with [Notepad++](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43984/using-notepad-with-miktex-on-windows) ... this I want also to achieve with Sublime Text (3)

Comment: Are you using Sublime Text 2 or 3? Why don't you try with a text editor dedicated such as TeXstudio?

Comment: That is where arara comes in handy!

Comment: @Aradnix I'm using Sublime Text 3. I use Sublime Text as a general IDE for most for my work now and I'd be happy not to be switching between editors!

Comment: @HarishKumar What about arara?

Comment: → https://github.com/cereda/arara

Comment: @Dorogz I use in that way Sublime Text also, but the version 2.02 nor 3.

Comment: @Aradnix could you please share how you combined Sublime Text with arara.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you very much for the information and the link. I am however, yet to figure out how to use arara with sublime text.

Comment: Please read the readme of LaTeXTools, particularly the build section. If you could do it, please post  an answer.

Comment: @Aradnix An answer please.

Comment: @HarishKumar What answer?

Comment: @Aradnix How you used sublime, may be with arara?

Comment: @HarishKumar I use Sublime Text for very simple tasks, in fact when I receive texts made with Word and for codification issues `pandoc` is unable to convert it. Sublime Text 2 highlights quotation marks in colour and is very useful for change them, also with multiple cursors and regex is very fast make corrections. I read only few about Arara, I haven't try it yet so I don't know how to use them together.

Comment: @Aradnix Oh! I get your point :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a while since this question was asked. 
But since I also struggled with LaTeXTools under Sublime Text 3 and TeXLive2018 (MacOS Mojave 10.14.5) I thought I'd share my working solution.

In my case, the glossaries package option `automake` solved the problem, described on page 19 in the Glossaries [Beginners' Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf).

So try

```
\usepackage[<your options>,automake]{glossaries}
```

Btw: I also (unsuccessfully) tried to understand how to create a custom build file for LaTeXTools. There still seems to be no proper documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I just struggled with more or less the same issue, except the `automake` option does not work properly, because I use an aux folder for all build files. 
If you want to run `makeindex` directly from ST3 with LaTexTools to compile the glossaries, just add the following line to the very beginning of your .tex file, before `\documentclass`:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.idx \jobname.glo -t \jobname.glg -s \jobname.ist -o \jobname.gls}
```

And if you use an aux folder called 'aux-files' it should look like this:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex aux-files/\jobname.idx aux-files/\jobname.glo -t aux-files/\jobname.glg -s aux-files/\jobname.ist -o aux-files/\jobname.gls}
```