# How to use Notepad++ together with TeX Live to write LaTeX?

Tags: texlive, editors, xepersian

I want to use Notepad++ as my text editor. However, I need to use TeX Live as the engine. The reason for the latter is that I want to write Persian using `xepersian` package and that works with TeX Live only. How can I configure my Notepad++ to have it working?

UPDATE: The solution for MiKTeX ([Using Notepad++ with MiKTeX on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43984/using-notepad-with-miktex-on-windows)) does not work for TeX Live.

Comment: Please have a look here https://www.tug.org/levels.html. You should use XeTeX as the engine. There is no way to compile a file using Notepad++, you should do it with console, e. g.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Notepad++ with MiKTeX on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43984/using-notepad-with-miktex-on-windows)

Comment: take a look at the `NppExec` plugin, from there you can run any commands you like.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman see my answer :)

Comment: @cmhughes oops, was wrong about compiling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the `NppExex` plugin using the plugin manager, and then press `<F6>` and paste the following code:

```
NPP_SAVE
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
xelatex $(NAME_PART).tex"
```

and click `Save` and then type, for example, `xelatex`

[image: screenshot]

Everytime you want to run `xelatex` on a file in the future, simply press `CTRL+F6`. If you have configured multiple scripts, you can select the appropriate one by pressing `F6`.

Comment: This works for me but how can I make it render the pdf using sumatrapdf?

Comment: I have a solution for that, will post it in the next few days when I'm at my laptop

Comment: I came up with a solution too, using the ideas from the post Phelype Oleinik provided. I will wait for yours and if its different, I will post mine as well.

Comment: My solution is a subset of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44046/6621