# Notepad++ Define Script to Save, Compile and View [Windows 10]

Tags: xetex, windows, editors, font-encodings

I am able to successfully compile using `XeLaTeX` and view the resulting PDF in `Sumatra` with the following run code in `Notepad++`:

```
cmd /c cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && xelatex.exe "$(FILE_NAME)" & "C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).pdf"
```

However, I have to manually save the file each time before running the script. Is there an additional command that I can insert at the beginning that saves the `.tex` file to the current directory? I'm not a programmer, so I'm probably missing something very simple. Here's an MWE for testing purposes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Notepad++ and \LaTeX}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: it's probably not advisable to use `--shell-escape` by default.

Comment: Try googling for `NPP_SAVEALL`...

Comment: OK, edited out `--shell-escape`. Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, the `NPP_SAVEALL` hint directed me to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43984/using-notepad-with-miktex-on-windows). I downloaded the [NppExec plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/NppExec%20Plugin%20v0.5.9.9%20dev/), manually extracted it to the `plugins` folder in `Notepad++`, and revised the run script to:

```
NPP_SAVEALL
cmd /c cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && xelatex.exe "$(FILE_NAME)" & "C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).pdf"
```

Now it works: save, compile and view in one keyboard shortcut! Hope this helps someone else!