# Notepad++ and Bibtex with Miktex

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, editors

I am interested in Notepad ++ as a Latex editor until now I used Texmaker since I would like to use one editor Notepad ++ instead of different code editors for R, Python, Stata and Latex.
I followed the following [tutorial](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43984/using-notepad-with-miktex-on-windows) to the letter and it works very well.

However, I need some more information to customize the code.
I need to compile large documents (my doctoral thesis).
I would like to know **how to simply compile `bibtex` on a document or else compile only `pdflatex` (without going through pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex -> pdf with Sumatra ) ?**

Comment: Hi Arnaud, and welcome to our forum. I am pretty sure Texmaker uses the same process of pdflatex->bibtex->pdflatex->pdflatex also. That is the way to compile a LaTeX document with BibTeX. You can open the pdf with Sumatra or any other pdf reader you might have (e.g. Adobe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Arnaud and welcome to TeX-SE.

As much as I appreciate your choice of "One editor to rule them all", I find it quite odd, as you don't have access to some tools.

If your are compiling at the command line you need `pdflatex <filename>.tex` to create to `pdf` and the `.aux` file, then apply `bibtex <filename>.aux` to create the `.bbl` file from your `.bib` file applying the format given by the `.bst` file. From personal experience, it is usually slower compiling from command line than from inside an editor, if your are doing minor changes (I may be wrong, but that's what I observe).

You may execute the commands `pdflatex` and `bibtex` independently, but the proper result, the one with correct references, needs the usage of the commands in the correct order.

Here are some comparisons of LaTeX editors: [Comparison of TeX editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors), [10 Best LaTeX Editors You Should Use](https://beebom.com/best-latex-editors/).

I tried some of them until reach TeXstudio. In TeXstudio, I have shortcuts. F5 for `pdflatex` and F8 for `bibtex`. I may configure it at will, or create my own. This the kind of tool that make easier to my brain to remember commands I once learned and used once or twice.

Bonus: And as you said you are writing your doctoral thesis, then it is highly recommend to read a little bit about managing large projects in LaTeX: [Multi-file LaTeX projects](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects), [On managing large documents](https://texblog.org/2016/06/20/on-managing-large-documents/).

Comment: Thank you very much **FHZ** for your answer.
My goal was precisely to avoid a Latex editor.
I found the ```arara``` documentation and it seems to be suitable for what I am looking for.
Thank you again for your responsiveness and your advice.
Best !

Comment: You are welcome @Arnaud. And btw, I would appreciate if you up-vote answers that indeed have helped you. This is how the forum knows what should be presented to more people and rewards people who answer question.